# Which number should be put on top of the pyramid "? 1 1 2 3 4"

Tags: logical-deduction

Suppose we have the pyramid

[image: logical question: pyramid, missing number]

Transcription:

```
  |?|
 |1|1|
|2|3|4|
```

[*The puzzle is from an example test for admission to a postgraduate degree at Sofia University, Faculty of Mathematics and Informatics, publicly available [here](https://www.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/sites/default/files/documents/priem/msc/example_test_kandmag_inf.pdf)*]

Which number should replace "?" on top?

The possible answers are: a) 0, b) 1, c) 3, d) 5

I believe the correct answer is a) 0, however, I am not sure whether my reasoning is sound enough.

I think the "1" on the right is the sum of the number to its left plus the closest touching number on top, starting from left to right (i.e. 1 + ?))

The "3" is the sum of the number to its left plus the closest touching number on top, starting from left to right (i.e. 2 + 1)

The "4" is the sum of the number to its left plus the closest touching number on top, starting from left to right (i.e. 3 + 1)

This logic, however, completely excludes the left "1" and the "2"

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Puzzles that are from other sources must be properly attributed.

Comment: @Deusovi thanks for the comment. I have made the necessary changes. How can I reopen the post? I don't see an option to vote to reopen. If it is not for this community, for which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's much much simpler than that:

> The number above two numbers is the difference.

Which would make the answer

> a) 0 still.

This logic works for all the numbers:

> Difference between 1 and 1 is 0, between 2 and 3 is 1 and 3 and 4 is 1.

Comment: It is actually the same rule as the OP's  (i.e. a = c-b instead of a+b=c).  But it is expressed in words in a simpler way.

Comment: @FlorianF pretty much, wording it like this also means that you don't have to worry about which number is bigger. The OPs rule would give a negative if say it was 4,3,2 instead (unless you include absolute values) so this is just a much simpler way to put it

Answer (score 0):

To make your idea work (and to complicate it a bit more):

> For each cell X, the the sum of the left and top cell (if existent) must equal X.
>  Furthermore, for each cell X, the difference between the the right cell and top cell (if existent) must equal X

so

> 0. Beastly Gerbils answer is most likely the intended one, but I wanted to make it work somehow :P